# Using MAXLOC with an array component which has ALLOCATABLE attribute

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The code is:

```
Type , public :: TS_VAR

  Complex , allocatable :: An_array (:)

End type TS_VAR 

Type ( TS_VAR ) , allocatable :: TS_PU (:)

Allocate ( TS_PU ( 24 ) , Stat = ALLOC_ERR )

If ( ALLOC_ERR .ne. 0 ) Stop ( !!! Memory allocation problem !!! )

Do j = 1 , 24 

   Allocate ( TS_PU(j)%An_array ( 1 : 13 ) , Stat = ALLOC_ERR )

   If ( ALLOC_ERR .ne. 0 ) Stop ( !!! Memory allocation problem !!! )

End do

!!! Calculation 

Do j = 1 , 24 

   Do i = 1 , 13

      TS_PU(j)%An_array ( i ) = cmplx ( ! Some calculation  )

   End do

End do

Logical , dimension ( 1 : 13 , 24 ) :: DM_mask = .false.

Forall( 1 : 5 , j = 1 : 24 ) DM_mask(i,j) = .true.

Write(*,*) maxloc ( abs ( TS_PU(:)%An_array ( : ) ) , mask = DM_mask )
```

Afther the compile proces was finished i got this message:
`Component to the right of a part reference with nonzero rank must not have the ALLOCATABLE attribute`

What is wrong with this example?
Is there intrinsic function for maximum value searching in specific sector of array?

Comment: Have you searched for the error message? It was treated here before.

Comment: Yes but I can not get from that question correct solution for my example.

Comment: You were asking what is wrong, not for a correct solution. But the solution is there too. You must use a do loop and check each `S_PU(i)%An_array ( : )` one by one.